# Using MYSQL to select rows between dates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im having a little problem with some MYSQL I have.

I need to be able to check if a period of time has already been booked in a holiday room.

My database uses DATETIME Fields and is set out like this:

[Database image link, as my rep is low](http://postimg.org/image/69e0518jj/)

I have a query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `caravanavail1` 
WHERE (`checkIn` BETWEEN '2014-01-07 14:00:00' AND '2014-01-08 10:00:00') 
OR (`checkOut` BETWEEN '2014-01-07 14:00:00' AND '2014-01-08 10:00:00')
```

I will always pass in two dates, however sometimes the dates may clash in many ways:

1. The checkIn maybe in the middle of another holiday and the checkOut may not.
2. The checkOut maybe in the middle of another holiday and the checkIn may not.
3. They maybe identical dates to another holiday.
4. The checkIn and checkOut dates I provide may BOTH be inside another booking.

I have been scratching my head for a few days with this, can anyone help me fix the SQL code above(I would prefer a single query, rather than two) to return what I need?

Comment: you don't mention the business logic behind this - what is a "holiday room", does it make a difference? what defines a holiday in relation to a date (weekend? date period?)? clarify what you WANT to do, and what are the actual restraints so that we can help.

Comment: Date period... The admin of that room can make holidays in that room as long as they want. They choose an checkIn Date and a checkOut Date.

That's all the information I need to check

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: I only use them because it what I was taught, but thanks :)

Comment: Still having issues :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        |________|      // date to book
    |______|            // condition 1
              |______|  // condition 2
          |____|        // condition 3 
    |________________|  // condition 4
```

If any of these 4 conditions results in a row, this means the booking can not be completed.

```
$in =  '2014-01-07 14:00:00';
$out = '2014-01-08 10:00:00';

SELECT * 
FROM `caravanavail1` 
WHERE 
  (`checkIn` <= '$in' AND `checkOut` <= '$out') // condition 1
  OR 
  (`checkIn` >= '$in' AND `checkOut` >= '$out')  // condition 2
  OR 
  (`checkIn` >= '$in' AND `checkOut` <= '$out') // condition 3
  OR 
  (`checkIn` <= '$in' AND `checkOut` >= '$out') // condition 4
```

As Marc B also notes, this can be further simplified:
all checkin times of the conditions are **before** the checkout time you want to book **AND** all check out times of the conditions are **after** the checkin time you want to book

comming down to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `caravanavail1` 
WHERE 
  (`checkIn` < '$out' AND `checkOut` > '$in')
```

sometimes it helps to visualize :)

Comment: The code you have provided makes the most sense to me, however your all your =< should be <= etc. However, using what you have provided(with the fix I just mentioned) I can no longer book any dates, even if there is a gap inbetween

Comment: fixed the operators. also note that if this query returns results, you can not book during the period. not the other way round.

Comment: I understand that, if you look at this image: http://postimg.org/image/4dh2c72at/ can see what I mean, I have asked for a week that is not already booked in my database and it is still returned

Answer (score 4):

Consider this diagram. Where `x` and `y` are the checkin/checkout time in question, and `p` and `q` are the checkin/checkout times in your database. There's various ways these two date ranges can overlap:

```
     x   y
p  q               // complete non-overlap, no conflict
   p  q            // partial overlap, conflict
      p q          // partial overlap, conflict
       p  q        // partial overlap, conflict
           p   q   // complete non overlap, no conflict
```

If you plot out the logic, you'll find that

```
 if (q >= x) && (p <= y) {
       ... there is a conflict
 }
```

coverse your bases.

Answer (score 2):

To arrive at the condition of when there is an overlapping range, it's easier to think about where there is no overlap and then reverse the condition. **Two ranges do *not* overlap if one is completely before or after the other**.

In SQL this translates to checkout date being before the given checkin date, or the checkin date being after the given checkout date:

```
SELECT * FROM `caravanavail1` WHERE NOT (checkOut <= '$in' OR checkIn >= '$out')
```

You can simplify this to:

```
SELECT * FROM `caravanavail1` WHERE checkOut > '$in' AND checkIn < '$out'
```